# How to make a bullet fly where it is pointed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a bullet and I need to direct its movement to where it is directed. I created a prefab of a bullet and now I’m cloning it to the coordinates that I’ve taken and now I want the bullet to fly to where it is directed

With this script I create a bullet

```
IEnumerator BulletSpawn()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Instantiate(PrefabOfbullet, BUlletPosition.position, Turell.rotation);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the transform.Translate(Transform.forward * bulletSpeed * time.deltaTime) in an update method on each individual bullet once it is created. You will need to give the bullets lifetimes aswell, or kill them on impact with the bounds of your game, or else your game will lag once you fire too many bullets. Good luck!